# Flutter how can i show icon on half box

Tags: flutter

I need to know how can I show the icon on the half end of the container. Like this

[image]

Just want to add this arrow on blank container

Comment: Use Stack and Positioned inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the effect with a Stack with Overflow visible or Clip behavior set Clip.none and Positioned widget.

I've used overflow: Overflow.visible in code below however it has been deprecated so you can use clipBehavior: Clip.none, instead.

Please see working code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: [
        Container(width: 175, height: 50, color: Colors.white),
        Positioned(
          left: 165,
          bottom: 15,
          child: Container(
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey),
            child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black, size: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i think it will not be responsive on small or large device ?

Comment: Right now in the code I've given fixed width and height. However this solution can be 100% responsive on small or large devices by providing relative positions.

Comment: i have adjust it by media query width height is it ok or not ?